# css layout and fixed during the scrolling

Tags: html, css, image, layout, fixed

I am making a css layout , until now I have something similar to this '''https://jsfiddle.net/4fLygdrc/1/ .'''
And I want to get something similar to this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hePhT.png)

The Mc donald logo and sections with burgers should be fixed during the scrolling
Instead of images of burgers , it is possible to use div's

Answer (score 0):

In case you want fixed elements when page is scrolled just add `postion:fixed` and the relative location such as top,right,bottom,left from which you want element to be fixed. Syntax- `top:0` for fixing element on top of page like nav bar.

Attached demo code snippet below please refer and have a look at [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp)

```css
.box {
               position: fixed;
               width: 100px;
               height: 100px;
               display: flex;
               justify-content: center;
               align-items: center;

          }

          .one {
               top: 0;
               left: 0;
               background-color: blue;
          }

          .two {
               top: 0;
               right: 0;
               background-color: rebeccapurple;
          }

          .three {
               bottom: 0;
               right: 0;
               background-color: cadetblue;
          }

          .four {
               bottom: 0;
               left: 0;
               background-color: aquamarine;
          }

          .five {
               top: 50%;
               left: 45%;
               background-color: yellow;
          }
```

```html
<div class="box one">Top-left</div>
<div class="box two">Top-right</div>
<div class="box three">Bottom-right</div>
<div class="box four">Bottom-left</div>
<div class="box five">Center</div>
```